# Translate logical address to page number and index

Tags: java, virtual-memory

I am supposed to convert the logicalAddress to pageNumber and index, but i don't know how to do this.
The logicalAddress is a five digit int (the logical address is given as decimal).
Any hints?

```
public byte read(int logicalAddress){
    //called by a process to read memory from its logical address
    //this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    byte data=0;

    //THIS IS THE PART I NEED HELP WITH *******

    //calculate pageNumber and index from the logical address
    int pageNumber = (logicalAddress/NbrOfPages);
    int index = (logicalAddress-(pageNumber*PageSize));

    //*****************************************

    //check if we get a pageFault
    if(pageTable[pageNumber]==-1){
        //call method to solve page fault
        pageFault(pageNumber);
        //the following two should be used in step 2 and 3 of the lab
        //pageFaultFIFO(pageNumber);
        //pageFaultLRU(pageNumber);
    }
    //read data from RAM
    int frame=pageTable[pageNumber];
    int physicalAddress=frame*PageSize+index;
    data=RAM[physicalAddress];
    //print result
    System.out.print("Virtual address: "+logicalAddress);
    System.out.print(" Physical address: "+physicalAddress);
    System.out.println(" Value: "+data);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is about x64 (Intel), there's Intel CPU manual for you.

Comment: It's a simulation of Paging, virtual memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with the page table size in bits. From that you need to break the address into two field (page table index and byte offset):

```
 unsigned long long MASK = PAGESIZE-1 ;
```

The the page table index is then

```
 unsigned long long index = (address & ~MASK) / PAGESIZE ;
```

and the offset is

```
 unsigned long long offset = address & mask ;
```

Alternatively:

```
unsigned long long index = address / PAGESIZE ;
unsigned long long offset = address % PAGESIZE ;
```